# How to update one row of a spreadsheet based on a row of another spreadsheet in MS Excel?

Tags: excel, magento

(For Magento Product Import):

How to update one row of a Sheet based on a row of another Sheet in MS Excel?

I have two Excel Sheets with about 1500 product data.

**Sheet_1** has *old_sku* and product name and **Sheet_2** has *new_sku* and product name. I want to update the **Sheet_1**'s *old_sku* based matching them with product name of *new_sku* of **Sheet_2**.

For example:

In Sheet_1 first product is "Aakash All In 1 350Gm" and its old_sku is 'Aakash-All-In-1-350Gm' while in Sheet_2 the same product's new_sku is 'SNA934'. There are about 1500 products and I need to update their SKUs with new ones so that I can import and update the product catalog in Magento.

[image]

[image]

Is there any quick way I can update column A (*old_sku*) of **Sheet_1** from column A (*new_sku*) of **Sheet_2**? While Googling, I came across suggestion using VLOOKUP but I don't know how to perform it in this context.

Comment: What does this have to do with Google Apps Script?

Comment: I thought thst in case it's not possible to do this with MS Excel, may be Google spreadsheet can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in either!  Place this in A2 of Sheet_1 and fill down.

```
=index(Sheet_2!A:A,match(B2,Sheet_2!B:B,0))
```

Comment: Bingo! Thanks a lot @mongoose36 for this awesome answer, it worked like a charm! Didn't thought it was this much easy!